# Ordering Logs of checkouts echoed from database by date

Tags: php, mysql

So i have to have a page where all of the logs from another one of our pages is echoed out.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `returnform` WHERE department_id=1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr class='divEnglish'> <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>" . " " . "<td>" . $row['returned_date'] . "</td>" . " " . "<td>" . $row['lost'] . "</td>" . " " . "<td>" . $row['lossnum'] . "</td>" . " " . "<td>" . $row['putback'] . "</td>","</tr>";

    };
```

I need all of the rows echoed out to be put in order from newest to oldest so that when people view the page the latest logs.

Comment: Is there any column that stores the created time or auto-increments?

Comment: The add some field like that and use `order by` that field in `desc`. your problem will be solved.

Comment: everything works now thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `order by` clause into your query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `returnform` WHERE department_id=1 ORDER BY create_date DESC";
```

I suppose you have date, when to record was created, the column name is `create_date`.